# JS Date Objects without TimeStamp values incorrectly go back one day

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In the terminal output below, the - (received) objects are being generated by converting moment.js objects back into Date objects. The + (expected) objects are created in the format `new Date("2018-05")` and appear to lose enough hours to fall back to 5 pm on the last day of the previous month:

```
        Object {
    -     "x": 2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    +     "x": 2018-04-30T17:00:00.000Z,
          "y": 260,
        },
        Object {
    -     "x": 2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    +     "x": 2018-05-31T17:00:00.000Z,
          "y": 160,
        },
        Object {
    -     "x": 2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    +     "x": 2018-06-30T17:00:00.000Z,
          "y": 40,
        },
```

Both the test code and test expectation code are on my computer so I don't understand why the date objects are slightly changing, does anyone know why? Here is my jest test code:

```
test('raw data is properly totalled (prepareData)', () => {
  expect(lineChart.prepareData(mockXYObjects(dataCloneMultiplier), 12, "month"))
    .toStrictEqual([
      {x : new Date("2018-05"), y : 13 * dataCloneMultiplier},
      {x : new Date("2018-06"), y : 8 * dataCloneMultiplier},
      {x : new Date("2018-07"), y : 2 * dataMultiplier},
    ])
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m guessing you live in the Western Hemisphere? Without a time stamp, Date objects are initialized to UTC time, not in your time zone. So the time will be midnight in UTC, but if you’re in the Eastern time zone, it will be 19:00EST on the previous day. The solution is to add your desired time zone to the Date string when you create it.

Comment: Ahh, that will explain it then. I'll see how to add the time zone offset to the date object